# Is "deabstractify" a word?

Tags: verbs

I'm currently working on an essay and in it I talk about how there's a computer program that allows me to do something and there was a time in my life where I worked very extensively with this program and so what I was doing every day started to feel more and more abstract, because working with a Graphical User Interface on a Computer is so far removed from concrete things that I can touch and feel and so I wanted to do something to **deabstractify** my life.

My solution was to learn the basics of a programming language that the program, that I was working with, was writing in the background and that way I was able to do some work without the program and see what my computer was actually doing, thus making this process a bit less abstract.

This is how I use it in my text:

> I felt this way, on that particular day, and so I decided to try to
> deabstractify my experience a little bit, by learning…

This seems logical to me, because I'm pretty sure that **"abstractify"** is a word and I know that I can just add a **"de"** to the beginning of verb to change its meaning to the opposite.

But Grammarly is telling me that **"deabstractify"** is not a word but Grammarly has no problem with: **"abstractify"** – Also English is not my native langue.

I though maybe I should use: **"deabstract"**, but according to Grammarly that's another unknown word.

Thank You!

Comment: It's even a little poem: I felt this way. – On that particular day. – And so I decided to try. – To deabstractify. :)

Comment: Of the readily available dictionaries on the internet, 'Wiktionary' gives the greatest number of headwords. While the paywalled OED is seen as the best proof of a candidate's wordness (if it's listed there, it is/was in the lexis), 'Wiktionary' gains in reputation and is a fair test for non-wordness. It lists _abstractify_ but not _deabstractify_. // 'Productive' is often used as if it is an absolute. _It isn't_. We'd all mark 'deimpignorate', 'depawn', 'debreak', 'deteach' ... incorrect in essays. 'The prefix "de-" and the suffix "-ify" are both _highly_ productive in English.' No guarantees.

Comment: Wiktionary has [devirtualize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devirtualize) although I think it's specifically as a computing term.

Comment: 1) Welcome! 2) Be aware that there's also an [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange; it's often a better fit for questions that deal with idiomatic usage ("what sounds more natural," "why do we say this") than with mechanics. 3) Be aware that "abstract" can be a transitive verb. I'm intrigued by your mention of *deabstract* and Grammarly, but can't find the article. Please edit to include links to the sources you've mentioned; to my mind that's plenty to qualify for re-opening. ...

Comment: ... 4) Be aware that "abstract" and derived words have [a specific meaning](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zttrcdm/revision/1) in computing. Ironically, it's possible that by learning "deeper" layers of programming language you were in fact increasing in abstraction, in this sense. In general, if a word has a specific meaning in your field, avoid using its broader meaning, to avoid confusion. 5) As I mentioned in a comment, no reason you have to force all your meaning into a single word. You have a concept to communicate; whatever word or phrase does the job *best* wins.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you, very much, for your input! This helped me a lot! :) | Concerning Grammarly: Sorry, there is no article on this subject, what I meant was:  When I write the word: "abstractify" inside of my Grammarly text editor, Grammarly does not mark it as a mistake. "deabstractify" and "deabstract" are marked as: "unknown words".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, very much, for your input! :)

Comment: Thanks! Note, though, I've written comments but the goal on Stack Exchange is to get good official answers to good answerable questions, so any time extra clarification is needed, please use the "edit" button to add information to the question itself, rather than through comments. And in general, don't put too much stock on what a spell checker (even one with some AI) does or doesn't recognize; they don't have a limitless dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix "de-" and the suffix "-ify" are both productive in English.

de- (usually added to a verb) gives the idea of removing something: deintensify; delouse, deforest, degrease, etc.

-ify (also (-fy) is from the Latin ficāre - to make, and can be added to words in the sense of "to make something [word]" and thus produce verbs: false - falsify; person - personify.

The test is usually "Given context, will it be generally understood?" I think that "deabstractify" *in the context given* would be understood as "remove the abstract nature of".

You will note that the order of the affixes indicates removal followed by creation in that new state.

The use of two affixes usually has a feeling of informality about it, akin to litotes, and new coinages should not be used in a formal context as there seems to be a little lightheartedness in coining words.

You might wish to consider losing the litotes and go for a positive statement: "I wanted to do something to make my life more real/concrete."

Comment: 'Productive' is often used as if it is an absolute. It isn't. We'd all mark 'deimpignorate', 'depawn', 'debreak', 'deteach' ... incorrect in say essays. 'The prefix "de-" and the suffix "-ify" are both highly productive in English.' No guarantees.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe I'm supporting your point (of "no guarantees"), but IMO if these some of these got scare quotes and hyphens—"de-teach"—I'd let them through, in some cases with a raised eyebrow. General point: words have meanings, and prefixes/suffixes have accustomed roles, and we can mix and match and coin new words *if we know what we're doing*, and *if the reader knows what we're doing*, and we can make bold leaps if the reader can follow us and understands that we understand that we're being risky. ...

Comment: ... If we want to Frankenstein a new usage, it helps if we explain ourselves (Lewis Carroll did, and *portmanteau* lives on). But the rule is, "if you have to ask whether you should"... you shouldn't.

Comment: @Andy Bonner No, the rule protocol is 'Check for currency in dictionaries and online first.' Then 'avoid lack of clarity if thinking about being innovative.' Then 'avoid ugliness unless considered a local asset'. Alongside 'Will the tutor / audience / ... appreciate this risqué style?'  Some people _have to ask_ more than others; growth should be guided, not stifled.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good points. Oh, and I don't know why I didn't try this before now, but a simple Google search does show many uses. No dictionary definitions, and some of the uses get scare quotes, and IMO it's certainly not the best wording for the OP's needs... but it's not novel.

Answer (score 2):

If "concrete" is the opposite of "abstract", then you could use "concretize" as the opposite of "abstractify".

> **concretize** *transitive verb*
> to make concrete, specific, or definite
> *tried to concretize his ideas*
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concretize)

Comment: There's also no requirement to use (or create) one single word. "Make X less abstract" or "make it more concrete" are just fine (or "tangible," or "focused," "applied," "specific" etc as applicable).